# No JSON response from PHP while connecting to database

Tags: java, php, android, json

I have tried to create simple Login and Register pages for sample app that I'm doing. I have used Volley library to handle request and response for the database and I used 000webhost.com to host my files and DB.

My LoginActivity is,

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final EditText uname =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.ed1);
    final EditText pword =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.ed2);
    Button Login=(Button)findViewById(R.id.b1);
    TextView register=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.regv);


    register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i= new Intent(MainActivity.this,RegisterActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });


    Login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final String username = uname.getText().toString();
            final String password = pword.getText().toString();

            // Response received from the server
            Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                        boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");

                        if (success) {
                            String name = jsonResponse.getString("username");

                            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Maps.class);
                            //intent.putExtra("username", username);
                            MainActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
                        } else {
                            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                            builder.setMessage("Login Failed")
                                    .setNegativeButton("Retry", null)
                                    .create()
                                    .show();
                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            };

            LoginRequest loginRequest = new LoginRequest(username, password, responseListener);
            RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);
            queue.add(loginRequest);
        }
    });


}
```

}

and the LoginRequest activity is,

```
public class LoginRequest extends StringRequest {
private static final String LOGIN_REQUEST_URL = "my_host/loginfile";
private Map<String, String> params;

public LoginRequest(String username, String password, Response.Listener<String> listener) {
    super(Method.POST, LOGIN_REQUEST_URL, listener, null);
    params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put("username", username);
    params.put("password", password);
}

@Override
public Map<String, String> getParams() {
    return params;
}
```

}

and the login.php file is,

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("host", "user", "pwd", "db");

$username = $_POST["username"];
$password = $_POST["password"];

$statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = ? AND password = ?");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "ss", $username, $password);
mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

mysqli_stmt_store_result($statement);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($statement, $username,$email, $password);

$response = array();
$response["success"] = false;

while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement)){
    $response["success"] = true;
    $response["username"] = $username;
    $response["email"] = $email;
    $response["password"] = $password;
}

echo json_encode($response);
```

?>

When I try to run the application and try a login request there is no response or error from the other side. I tried adding records in the database table and tried to verify by logging in but still there is no response. Please advise, I'm not that proficient in PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would first try out `print_r($statement)`, to see if the database is even returning data in the first place. What I think might also be happening is in the prepared statement you are calling for every column in the record with the `*` but in the `mysqli_stmt_bind_result` you are only binding the results to 3 variables, while there may be more variables than that coming back. I would try something similar to this:

```
     $statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT username, email, password FROM user WHERE username = ? AND password = ? LIMIT 1");
    //Change username, email, password to whatever the equivalent are in the database if they are different. 
The Limit 1 also limits you to only 1 record that matches that criteria, which should be the case anyway, but prevents it from running through the whole database.
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "ss", $username, $password);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

        mysqli_stmt_store_result($statement);
        mysqli_stmt_bind_result($statement, $username,$email, $password);
```

P.S. I don't know why you would need to return the password, or if you are just testing your database, but if this is going to be a live production code, do not return a users password and especially do not store a users plain text password in the database, learn how to hash and salt a users password and store that instead. Just some extra friendly advice.

Comment: thanks for the advice, I will learn to salt passwords and critical stuff before storing them, also I had sorted the issue, I changed the bind variables correctly and I had to change my connect URL to 'http' in order for it to work, still not sure why 'https' didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are getting no connection to the DB server. You should double check your call to mysqli_connect().

```
$con = mysqli_connect("host", "user", "pwd", "db");
```

Make sure you are replacing the "host", "user", "pwd", and "db" strings with the actual database connection values. They would not work as displayed above.

Here is another way to look at using variables in the mysqli_connect() function.

```
$dbHost = "host";
$dbUser = "username";
$dbPass = "password";
$dbName = "database";
$con = mysqli_connect($dbHost, $dbUser, $dbPass, $dbName);
```

Replace the values in the quotes with your database connection values.

Comment: thanks for replying I had used the correct credentials, that wasn't the issue.